# XamCurrencyEditor mask keeps "zero" when value is edited

Tags: wpf, infragistics

I have a problem setting correctly a mask for an editor control. I'm writing a WPF allication and the control in question is Infragistics XamCurrencyEditor.

I set up a following style to handle the mask for each XamCurrencyEditor:

```
<Style x:Key="ValidatedCurrencyFieldStyleInline" TargetType="{x:Type igEditors:XamCurrencyEditor}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource ValidatedFieldStyleInline}">
    <Setter Property="Mask" Value="{}{double:-9.4}"/>
</Style>
```

I apply the style in the following way:

```
<igEditors:XamCurrencyEditor Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource ValidatedCurrencyFieldStyleInline}"
                                 Value="{Binding Path=UnearnedPremiums, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" IsReadOnly="{Binding Path=IsLocked}" />
```

By default, when there is no value the editor displays "0.0000" which I'm happy with. When I click the editor (to enter edit mode) it keeps displaying "0.0000". This is also okay.

Now my issue: I'm tabbing into the control, or clicking it once. When I start typing a number, say `123456789876`, it keeps the first zero and doesn't override it. So the result actually is `123456780.9876`. Keeping the "0" on the first position is a bit unintuitive. What I would like to achieve is actually this result: `123456789.8760`.

It sounds trivial but I tried different combination of mask and format properties and `{double:-9.4}` is closest to what I want to achieve.

I also tried `"999999999.9999"` but then it's impossible to use negative numbers (negative mask requires using "n" in the format); also this format hides existing number when entering edit mode. And when I apply `"nnnnnnnnn.nnnn"` instead I have the same issue as when applying `{double:-9.4}`. I've played with format as well but it only influences the way the number is displayed when not in edit mode.

Answer (score 1):

You might try something to set where the SelectionStart is set.  Does it depend WHERE in the editor you click, ie. what position?  I had to do this to some of my XamCurrencyEditor controls in the code-behind (this should be acceptable MVVM because it is view stuff):

```
<igEditors:XamCurrencyEditor  Margin="0"
                Value="{Binding SelectedItem.VendorBalanceDefaultThreshold, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                         Style="{StaticResource MoneyStyle}" Theme="[Current]"
                                         ValueType="{x:Type sys:Decimal}" PromptChar=" " InvalidValueBehavior="RevertValue"
                                         ClipMode="Raw" DisplayMode="IncludeBoth" SelectAllBehavior="SelectEnteredCharacters"
                                         NullText="Value Required" SpinButtonDisplayMode="MouseOver"
                                         GotFocus="XamCurrencyEditorGotFocus" PreviewMouseDown="XamCurrencyEditor_PreviewMouseDown" >
                </igEditors:XamCurrencyEditor>
```

and the code-behind:

```
private void XamCurrencyEditor_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        XamCurrencyEditor currencyEditor = sender as XamCurrencyEditor;

        if (currencyEditor != null)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(currencyEditor.Text))
            {
                if (currencyEditor.SelectionStart < 11)
                {
                    currencyEditor.SpinIncrement = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    currencyEditor.SpinIncrement = 0.01;
                }
            }
        }
    }

private void XamCurrencyEditorGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        XamCurrencyEditor currencyEditor = sender as XamCurrencyEditor;

        if (currencyEditor != null)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(currencyEditor.Text))
            {
                currencyEditor.SelectAll();
                if (currencyEditor.SelectionStart < 11)
                {
                    currencyEditor.SpinIncrement = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    currencyEditor.SpinIncrement = 0.01;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

the style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type igEditors:XamCurrencyEditor}" x:Key="MoneyStyle">
    <Setter Property="Mask" Value="{}{currency:-8.2:c}" />
</Style>
```

try this out and modify to fit your unique need

Comment: Eventually I ended up with a different solution: a custom behaviour to select all text on focus. When typing whilst the value is selected the control will replace whatever is in it and won't keep the zeros. But +1 for working solution. Thanks.